# jquery - count character in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this textarea where their is a character limit. How to do it? I don't want the "character remaining type" like: "250 characters remaining". I want this type: "250/250" until it will go "0/250". How to do this?

HTML:

```
<textarea maxlength=250>Text Here</textarea>
<span id="charCount">250/250</span>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Are you stuck on any particular implementation detail?

Comment: <Script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('textarea').keyup(function () { 
             console.log($(this).val().length); 
       $('span').html((250 - $(this).val().length) +"/250");
            });
       });
 </Script>

Answer (score -3):

```
    //try this   
   <textarea maxlength=250 id="text">Text Here</textarea>
     <span id="charCount">250/250</span>

   <script type="text/javascript" >
      $('#text').keypress(function() {
         var $self = $(this);
         var max = parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength"));

         if ($self.text().length > max) {
           return false;
         }

         $("#charCount").html((max - $self.text().length) + "/" + max);
      });
   </script>
```